# Time-trend analysis?

Tags: r, function, time

i've a db in which each individual has several evaluation of a certain test during time:

```
id, time, test
1,01/01/2000,40
1,05/03/2001,42
1,12/08/2006,44
2,03/03/1999,34
2,04/05/2001,34
2,03/07/2003,36
3,04/08/2007,40
3,05/09/2007,44
3,06/09/2012,48
```

I would like to know whether each individual goes through any plateaus (i.e.consecutive equal values of the test during time) and in the case how long (expressed as days) these are.

Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Comment: check out `rleid` from `data.table`: ?rleid and `group_by` from `dplyr`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use base R's `rle` for this. E.g.,

```
by(df, df$id, function(x) {
  d <- as.data.frame(t(do.call(rbind, rle(df$scale))))
  d[d$lengths > 1, ]
  })

df$id: 1
  lengths values
4       2     34
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
df$id: 2
  lengths values
4       2     34
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
df$id: 3
  lengths values
4       2     34
```